# ¿Como rellenar un elemento html con una imagen?

Tags: html, css, response

Buenos días!
Estoy haciendo el front-end de una app web, y me gustaría rellenar los botones y nav-tab con imágenes. Cual seria el atributo, o la regla CSS adecuada, para que la imagen se "estire" y adapte al tamaño del objeto? La idea es que las imágenes actúen de manera "responsiva".

Gracias!

Comment: Mirate la propiedad CSS: background
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a hacer en CSS, podrías hacerlo por medio background-cover:

```
background-image: url("..");
background-size: cover;
```

Más información: http://vagabundia.blogspot.com/2010/01/la-propiedad-background-size.html

Answer (score 0):

En el HTML colocas un valor al boton:

```
button value="botonimagen"
ó
input type="button" value="botonimagen"
```

En el CSS colocas el fondo al valor colocado en el HTML:

```
.botonimagen{
  background-image:url(imagen.jpg);
}
```